# Spring Security OAuth2 client: access the expires_in value

Tags: spring-security

I'm using the current release of Spring Security as an OAuth2 client.

It is working fine. But how do I get the value of the `expires_in` the authentication server sent back along with the Access and Refresh tokens, etc?

Or does Spring Security convert the `expires_in` to a timestamp with a `timeLeft` method or similar?